# Additional Pages listed as Views in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

### The Situation:

I have customized the Bug Database template for SharePoint 2007 using SharePoint Designer.  Specifically, I have edited the additional .aspx pages included with the template that are located inside the Bugs list.  These are just simple edit forms and my customizations are very minor.

I have verified that the *Supporting Files* are correctly selected (New, Edit, Display).  These forms have all been edited as well.  I have the following .aspx pages (Non Views) in the Bugs List:

- `Activate.aspx`
- `Close.aspx`
- DispForm.aspx - *Supporting Display Form*
- EditForm.aspx - *Supporting Edit Form*
- NewForm.aspx
- ResolveForm.aspx
- NewIssue.aspx - *Supporting New Form*
- `Resolve.aspx`

### The Problem:

On any of the views, the view dropdown contains 3 non views that correspond to the Activate, Close, and Resolve forms in addition to the actual view choices.  Choosing these "views" just opens these forms.

Obviously, SharePoint is picking up any .aspx pages in the List that aren't supporting files and assuming they are views.  Strangely, this was **NOT** the case for these files before I modified them using SharePoint Designer.  Additionally, The NewForm.aspx page was **NOT** modified (I just created a new form that is now a supporting file), and even though it is not marked as a supporting file, it does not incorrectly show up in my views list.

### The Conclusion:

There must be some setting to mark these files as non views without them being supporting files.  I have looked through the NewForm.aspx and compared it to my modified forms and can find no obvious difference that should have any bearing on this.

Perhaps you have had this problem before or are aware of how to fix this issue?  If so, here are some **easy points!**  Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have been setup as a view (which it sounds like they have been), try making the `<View>` hidden to remove it from the view list

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms438338.aspx

```
  <View BaseViewID="1" 
        Type="HTML" 
        WebPartZoneID="Main"        
        DisplayName="Activate" 
        RowLimit="100" 
        ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png"          
        Hidden="TRUE"
        Url="Activate.aspx">
```

I dont think you can make them `<Form>` elements, as it only accepts DisplayForm, EditForm, or NewForm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478121%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: It seems like you are suggesting that I should edit the schema.xml file for the list.  If this is correct, how can I edit this using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: any word on how to do this with SharePoint Designer, or were you suggesting another method?

Comment: i know in sharepoint 2010, if you open the aspx file, there is a <View> element embeded somewhere on the page, sometimes as an escaped xml string. you can add the Hidden="True" property there. i cant actually connect to a sharepoint 2007 instance right now, but does sharepoint 2007 have the same thing?